# changing python log level on runtime

Tags: python, logging

In log4net we can change the log level in the xml config file on runtime from DEBUG to ERROR for example and the change take effect immediately.

is there a way to do it in python? i haven't figured out yet how to do it.

In addition, for some reason, when the logging file is set without any folder (see example of the config i use at the bottom - yaml dictionary config file), it fails to rotate files. if i change it to be at any other path other the one that the code is in, it works like a charm and 20 files get created.
i will be happy to get any help.
thanks!

dictionary config extract example:

```
  rotatingFile:
        class : logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        formatter:  jajahFormater
        level: DEBUG
        filename: chs.log
        maxBytes: 20
        backupCount: 20
```

Answer (score 1):

You really should have posted two questions.

1. The `.NET` infrastructure watches the config file and automatically loads it to get the changes, but Python doesn't - so you would need to code this yourself.
2. The `chs.log` file in the code directory may be held open (e.g. in an editor), which would prevent rollover - I can't tell without more information.

Comment: i used process explorer to check if there are other handles to this file and they were none.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel) use `Logger.setLevel()` at logger level and `Handler.setLevel()` at handler level

```
import logging

my_logger = logging.getLogger('myloggername') #Assumes you have configured the logger somewhere
my_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Comment: You can define it in a config file and change the config file. But you'll have to restart the process. For _runtime_ I'm not aware of something out of the box although you could probably watch for changes in the config file and reload logging whenever that happens. Alternatively you can just extract the changed parameter 'log_level' and call the `setLevel()` function. But that would have to be done in a watcher process or something